# Does area51 provide a list of sites that have been launched?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

Someone visits area51 and wants to see what sites have graduated the staging stage and have been launched already...is this feature available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  There is a tab specifically for this.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched

---

**This portion of the answer is before the launched tab was added.  The methods are still valid, but not as important with the new launched tab.**

A poor side effect of losing our domain names.

A51 will show you a graduated site, but only if you search for it, which doesn't help this scenario.

https://stackexchange.com/sites gives no indication as to the status of the site other than the icon not being the graph paper behind letters.

The current best way to do this will be to look at the footer here, on the trilogy, or on a graduated site as the footer only lists graduated sites.

Comment: Graduated sites do have a "non-beta looking" icon, but that's a very weak indication. It would be nice if the sites page had some clear marking for graduated sites, or at least a filter of some sort.

Comment: @Tim, I edited this info in, thanks.

Comment: For some reason, in the case of OnStartups, their logo is not two letters, even though they're still in beta (at this time).