# There should be a page for Area 51's graduated sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does area51 provide a list of sites that have been launched?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66853/does-area51-provide-a-list-of-sites-that-have-been-launched)

Hmmm, so I really like to wander into the graduated pages to see what design they ended up with, and just to look around, however... I just realized there I can't find a list of the graduated sites!

If you search for a graduated site it will appear and say when did its beta end and they actually have a little rocket icon.. But still...

I think it would be nice to add a list of graduated sites, and maybe even information of how well they are doing.

EDIT:

OK, so there's a tiny list in the footer of the page.. but I still think that a Graduates section in Area 51 would be nice. It could help to show people that anybody can come up with a great SE site, by showing how an SE site that started just like any other humble Area 51 proposal is now a vibrant site :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66853/does-area51-provide-a-list-of-sites-that-have-been-launched

Answer (score 0):

On the footer of every StackExchange page is the list of completed websites, such as SO, SU, MSO, etc.

As of this post, it links to [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: oh, well thats a little hidden :P I'll wonder what will there are dozens of SE sites

Comment: yes but I think that bangoker is right, it makes absolute sense for the Area51 site itself to have a 'graduates' page. (And the footer you mention *isn't* on the Area51 site).